# How do I enable the emusic store in Banshee?

Tags: 11.04, banshee

Does anyone know how I can enable the emusic store extension as demoed at http://blogs.gnome.org/wjjt/2011/03/13/emusic-in-banshee/ ? I have enabled the "eMusic Import" extension available in Preferences->Extensions, but that only lets you import emusic files, as opposed to browsing the web site within Banshee (as with Amazon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a feature of the next version of Banshee which has not been released yet. You could install the daily build [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~banshee-team/+archive/banshee-daily) but this is **experimental** and **will likely break** from time to time.

A much **safer option** is to wait for the next stable release which will be available in this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~banshee-team/+archive/ppa).